# $\sqrt 2$ in $F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, radicals

Is there a way to find out if $\sqrt 2$ exists in $F_p$ depending on p?

Comment: Iff $p\equiv \pm1$, or $2$ modulo $8$. See any textbook on number theory.

Comment: Magic words: “quadratic character of $2$”.